# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS problems

Tags: 14.04, lts

I have a login loop problem, I cannot install any packages to fix anything, what can I do now? I can't load a live disk to reboot or reinstall the OS. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "login loop", do you mean you can't log in and just get kicked to the log in screen after entering your password, no desktop access ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: i would enter my password and i would get kicked back to the login page again

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error for many on the forum, give this a try:

press ctrl+alt+f2 at login login to the console

now try to run the update:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Please once complete

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Can you provide the source for this ? You say "This seems to be an error for many on the forum" but provide no sources for context on WHY this will work, if you add your source, and it checks out, then +1

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: I don't see updating apt as a solution anywhere on that page, how would updating apt fix a session manager issue ?

Comment: This is simply an initial suggestion before recommending to reinstall lightdm. the intention is to attempt to update anything that might be broken first

Comment: That is a good practice ,yes, fair enough.

Comment: If lightdm repair doesn't work we can always go for removal of lightdm and go for gdm as the other link describes and  worked for me on my old Dell E6410 with nvs3100.

Comment: I keep getting "Err" messages and it fails to fetch anything for the update or upgrade

Comment: can you post 'nano /etc/apt/sources.list'   and are you connected to the internet?

Comment: how do i post that

Comment: such as if you type 'ifconfig' what is the output?

Comment: where do i type it? im using two separate computers rn.

Comment: The computer that is in a console, type ifconfig or try typing: ping google.com

Comment: its okay i reinstalled it by booting it through my BIOS

Comment: Is everything working now?